# Dotwhiskerplot relabel_predictors - relabelling not working for interactions?

Tags: r, label

I have a question related to the dot-whisker-plot relabel command for the Coefficient plots. I relabeled all the variables, however for the interaction term, the old variable names appear, they dont change to the new labels I assign. The first variable "China's finanical aid" is the same as the one in the interaction "ChinaAssis21_log: China_political_power".. Do you know how to fix this issue?
Here is the command:

```
c1<- dwplot(m2) %>%
      relabel_predictors(c(ChinaAssis21_log= "China's 
               Financial Aid(logged)",
      China_political_power="China's Political Influence",
      gender = "Gender",
      socioecon_stat = "Socioeconomic Status",
       eu_support = "EU Support", age = "Age")) +
      theme_bw() + xlab("Coefficient") + ylab("") +
      geom_vline(xintercept = 0, colour = "grey60", linetype = 2) +
      ggtitle("Coefficient Plot with Coarsened Matched Data") +
      theme(legend.position = "none") +
      scale_colour_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

[image]